# Android Google Map How to marker Position from ArrayList

Tags: java, android, google-maps, arraylist, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using google maps on my app. I have an ArrayList where has lat, long and other information. I want to make click on a marker and go to other `Activity` with specific marker info to show details.

I have used this code but always get the last position of ArrayList. How to get each position's information?

```
package com.teledaktar.activities.mapsAndLocation;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Circle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
import com.teledaktar.R;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.teledaktar.activities.blogActivities.BlogActivity;
import com.teledaktar.activities.root.MainActivity;
import com.teledaktar.api.AppClient;
import com.teledaktar.api.ApplicationConfig;
import com.teledaktar.model.blog.BlogContent;
import com.teledaktar.model.hospital_model.Hospital;
import com.teledaktar.model.nearestHospitalModels.Hospitals;
import com.teledaktar.model.nearestHospitalModels.NearestHospitalContent;
import com.teledaktar.utility.Constants;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import dmax.dialog.SpotsDialog;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class DoctorLocationOnMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener, SensorEventListener, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    double currentLatitude, currentLongitude;
    float mDeclination;
    private SpotsDialog pDialog;
    private Marker myMarker;
    int clickPosition;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_doctor_location_on_maps);
        pDialog = new SpotsDialog(DoctorLocationOnMapsActivity.this, R.style.Custom);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);

        checkLocationPermission();
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        //LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        // mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        // mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(DoctorLocationOnMapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(DoctorLocationOnMapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            // mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            return;
        }


        // Toast.makeText(this, Double.toString(currentLattitude), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //specify latitude and longitude of both source and destination
        /*Polyline line = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                .add(new LatLng(currentLattitude, currentLongitude), new LatLng(24.21,88.84))
                .width(10)
                .color(Color.MAGENTA));

*/



        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            return;
        }

        String lattitudeString = Constants.latitude;
        String longitudeString = Constants.longitude;

        if (lattitudeString == null) {

            lattitudeString = "23.7277";
        }
        if (longitudeString == null) {

            longitudeString = "90.4106";
        }

        Double hospitalLat = Double.parseDouble(lattitudeString);
        Double hospitalLong = Double.parseDouble(longitudeString);


/*
            LatLng bagha = new LatLng(hospitalLat,hospitalLong);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(bagha).title("Marker in Hospital"));*/

        /**
         * find current location . latitude and longitude
         */


        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mLastLocation == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enable GPS and give location permission to get dirrection ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            currentLatitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            currentLongitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();


            getNearestHospitalApiData(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

        /*    Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                    .add(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude), new LatLng(hospitalLat, hospitalLong))
                    .width(10)
                    .color(Color.GREEN));
*/

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));

        //stop location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }


    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

    public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                        return;
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }


    /*
      for changing auto rotation
     */

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {
            float[] rotMat = new float[9];
            float[] rotMat1 = new float[9];
            SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(
                    rotMat, event.values);
            float[] orientation = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(rotMat, orientation);
            float bearing = (float) (Math.toDegrees(orientation[0]) + mDeclination);
            updateCamera(bearing);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    private void updateCamera(float bearing) {
        CameraPosition oldPos = mMap.getCameraPosition();

        CameraPosition pos = CameraPosition.builder(oldPos).bearing(bearing).build();
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(pos));
    }

    public void getNearestHospitalApiData(Double latitude, Double longitude) {

        /**
         * HERE API CALL WILL BE ADDED
         */

        show();

        String lats = Double.toString(latitude);
        String longs = Double.toString(longitude);


        final ApplicationConfig apiServiceReader = AppClient.getApiService();
        Call<NearestHospitalContent> list = apiServiceReader.getNearestHospitals(lats, longs);
        list.enqueue(new Callback<NearestHospitalContent>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<NearestHospitalContent> call, Response<NearestHospitalContent> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    hide();

                    if (response.body().getStatus_code().equals("200")){


                        ArrayList<Hospitals> nearestHospitals = response.body().getHospitals();

                        if (nearestHospitals.size() > 0) {


                            for (int i = 0; i < nearestHospitals.size(); i++) {
                                Double latitudes = Double.parseDouble(nearestHospitals.get(i).getLatitude().substring(0, 5));
                                Double longitudes = Double.parseDouble(nearestHospitals.get(i).getLongitude().substring(0, 5));

                                LatLng hospitalMarker = new LatLng(latitudes, longitudes);

                                myMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(hospitalMarker)
                                        .title(nearestHospitals.get(i).getName())
                                        .snippet(nearestHospitals.get(i).getDescription())
                                        .alpha(0.8f)
                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

                               // mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(hospitalMarker).title(nearestHospitals.get(i).getName()).alpha(0.8f));
                                myMarker.showInfoWindow();
                                Constants.NEAREST_HOSPITAL_NAME = nearestHospitals.get(i).getName();
                                clickPosition =i;

                                System.out.println("clicked"+i);



                            }

                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(DoctorLocationOnMapsActivity.this, "Currently No Nearest Hospital found at this position ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }

                } else {
                    hide();
                    Toast.makeText(DoctorLocationOnMapsActivity.this, "not success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<NearestHospitalContent> call, Throwable t) {
                hide();

                Toast.makeText(DoctorLocationOnMapsActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

        Toast.makeText(DoctorLocationOnMapsActivity.this,Integer.toString(clickPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            Intent intent = new        Intent(DoctorLocationOnMapsActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }


      /*  Integer clickCount = (Integer) marker.getTag();


        if (clickCount != null) {
            clickCount = clickCount + 1;
            marker.setTag(clickCount);
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    marker.getTitle() +
                            " has been clicked " + clickCount + " times.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }*/


        return false;
    }




    private void show() {
        pDialog.show();
        pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.waiting_data_string));
    }

    private void hide() {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }


}
```

Comment: You are updating clickPosition =i;always at the end of the nearestHospitals arrayList. You should update it when onMakerClick

Comment: Thanks .  How can i update clickPosition in onMarkerClick ?